# ExtJS How to compare form values to a selected record

Tags: javascript, forms, button, extjs, panel

Start by saying I'm new to ExtJS, and have spent way too much time trying to figure out this one little piece.
I am building a small grid to display 3 columns, with a button to add a new record, a button to delete the selected record, and a button to use the new record form to update the selected record.
Right now I have the new and delete buttons working. The Update button calls the form and fills it with the selected record, but I am having trouble within the form's submit function to figure out if the current form data matches the selected record, to decide if it will update an existing record or make a new one. This has to be based off of what the user selected and not an individual column.

Here is the submit button where I am having trouble figuring out the way to reference it. I have tried numerous ways from stackoverflow and sencha forums.

```
buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function(){

                if ( /* The field values match the selected record */) {
                    //update the existing record

                } else {
                    //Add new record
                    Ext.getCmp('testGrid').store.add(testForm.getValues());
                }

                Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getView().refresh();
                testForm.hide();
                testForm.reset();
            }
        }
    ]
```

And here are the buttons calling the form to show.

```
items: [
            {
                //New button calls the Add Record form to pass inputs to the store
                text: 'New',
                scope: this,
                handler: function(){
                    testForm.show();
                }
            },{
                text: 'Update',
                scope: this,
                handler: function(){
                    //WIP
                    var selection = Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    if (selection) {
                        testForm.show();
                        testForm.loadRecord(selection);
                    }

                }
            }//Delete button is irrelevant 
        ]
```

The store is testStore
The grid is testGrid
and the form is testForm

I know it may be stupid but I have become stumped on how to proceed with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your record have some kind of identifier? Or is a match determined solely based on the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Your record should have an unique identifier.
(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html)
Search for the property idProperty in Ext.data.Model. The default identifier is 'id'.
Every record in your store should have an unique id that you can use to check for records in your grid

> Your code edited

```
            buttons: [{
text: 'Submit',
handler: function() {
    //get record via form
    //get grid
    if (grid.getStore().findRecord('id', record.get('id'))) {
        //update the existing record

    } else {
        //Add new record
        Ext.getCmp('testGrid').store.add(testForm.getValues());
    }

    Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getView().refresh();
    testForm.hide();
    testForm.reset();
}
  }]
```

I created a sencha fiddle with a working example for you if you want to test it.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31fr

I hope this helps you!

Comment: The id is helpful, but I tried this with both using the default id and adding a key to the data model and still nothing. What is "record" referencing, does it reference the record loaded into the form instance?

Comment: Yes. It's a reference to the grid record that is binded to the form.
In my sencha fiddle example I did a loadRecord(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) on the form with the selected record in the grid. That way the grid record is binded to the form and you have access to all data for this record.

Comment: Am I doing this wrong?
My code errors out when trying to get the record via either the default ID or the key.
`var recReplace = Ext.getCmp('testGrid').store.findRecord('key', record.get('key'));`
or
`var recReplace = Ext.getCmp('testGrid').store.findRecord('id', record.get('id'));`

Comment: If you check out the fiddle code you can see that I'm doing the same thing. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31fr
What error are you getting when executing this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Exists several ways to resolve your problem.
1) Add to form some flag before open. For example  - `testForm.caseType = 'edit'/'add'` or testForm.isEdit = true/false; And when you submit form you have to check `if(testForm.caseType == 'edit') { store.findRecord('keyParamName', keyParamValue)` and update/replace it }
2) Other way when you open form, your should remove record and after submit always add new (but in this case you may lose data if you close form without submit).
3) If you open form as modal window  - your grid will stay with selection, so you can after submit get record .....`getSelection()[0]` again and update it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with using the caseTypes, that at least works to get me into the proper mode I need the form behaving in.
Quick question though, how should I update the value syntax wise? and using statements such as `record.get('key')` don't seem to be useful to me

Comment: If you have no unique value (like some entity id) in record and can't use selection after open form, try to add to form one more parameter testForm.recordId = "rowIndex of your record". It's not good solution but it will work. As usually in the same cases, I have dataIndex - id. And check if it is null - its create mode, if not null - update mode. Then save new data in DB and reload store from server.

Comment: And one more variant for work with records locally - add to form your record - testForm.dataRecord  = selection. Then after submit, you load your form data into testForm.dataRecord and make testForm.dataRecord.commit() or Ext.getCmp('testGrid').getStore().commitChanges();